# Add character automatically in EditText once click enter

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to automatically put a "-" after click enter for the next line in `editText`. How am i going to do it?

Comment: What did you try so far? And which errors do you get?

Comment: please put your code where you getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture `KEYCODE_ENTER` event and do a specific action you should use a `OnEditorActionListener` like this:

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    return false;
                } else if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT || (keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                    String text = textView.getText().toString() + "-";
                    mEditText.setText(text);
                    mEditText.setSelection(text.length());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
editText.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher(){
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged( CharSequence txt, int start, int before, int count ) {
                if( -1 != txt.toString().indexOf("\n") ){
//                    new line available                        
// TODO: 5/1/2018 do your logic here 
                    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString().replace("\n","-"+"\n"));

                }
            }
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ... define edittext text max length then it reached then going next line then put - sign.

```
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length()<=20){

            }
            else{
                et.setText("\n -");
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });
```